# Загрузка файла на сервер [PHP]

Tags: php, fileupload

Не понимаю почему не работает загрузка картинки на сервер

```
header('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');

mkdir("images"); 
foreach ($_FILES["images"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]);
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/images/$name");
    }
}
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: потому что `/images/$name` это абсолютный путь от самого корня диска, а не директории вашего скрипта?

Answer (score 0):

Строку `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "/images/$name");` замените на `move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/$name");`
В пхп указываются абсолютные пути, от корня диска. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - корень.